# How to include tailwind css, as part of remoteEntry, module-federation

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, webpack-module-federation, nrwl

I am using @nrwl/react cli for maintaining mono repo. I can see when i am consuming remoteEntry1 in my shell-app (outside of this monorepo project), it is not including css file anywhere in the .js file [reason is well obvious : https://malcolmkee.com/blog/using-tailwindcss-with-module-federation/]
I wanted to follow the @nrwl-tailwind-postcss way and here to check how we can have the settings in place, so that my remoteEntry1.js either include that css in js file or it supports download of the css content from hosted app (where ever remoteEntry1 is sitting).

-app1

- remoteEntry1.js

-app2

- remoteEntry2.js